# Handling Dialog or Alert Box with Puppeteer Sharp

Tags: asp.net-core, automation, epplus, puppeteer-sharp

I am using **Puppeteer Sharp** and **Epplus** library on Asp.net core to perform some **Automation** on a website.

**Scenario:** Using Epplus I am reading data from an excel File and saving those data into local variables. Then, I am going to example.com/login to login with the login info. After performing login. I am looping through all the rows in the excel sheet to perform following operations:

- Fetching URL, DOB, NAME, ID from excel using Epplus
- Going to that url
- Inputting those values into specified field of that url
- Finally clicking the verify button.
- If the data is verified then type Verified in the status column else Not Verified.

Now, the issue is when the DOB, name, ID is correct, after clicking VERIFY button No Alert box/ Dialog box is shown Only The Verify Button's parent  element's style becomes Display: None and Update Button's parent element 's style become Display:block. But If the information is incorrect then after clicking the VERIFY button A Browser Alert is shown saying 'There is a Mismatch in {x} data'.

This is the code I have written,

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Uploader(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                // Handle invalid file upload.
                return View("Index");
            }

            var executablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe";
            ExcelPackage package;  // Declare package here

            try
            {
                using var stream = new MemoryStream();
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                package = new ExcelPackage(stream);  // Initialize package

                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

                var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
                {
                    Headless = false,
                    IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true,
                    ExecutablePath = executablePath
                });
                var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
                var userId = "XXXXXX";
                var password = "xxxxxx";

                await page.GoToAsync("SomeURL");
                await page.TypeAsync("input[name=userid]", userId);
                await page.TypeAsync("input[name=password]", password);
                await page.ClickAsync(".login100-form-btn");
                await Task.Delay(3000);

                // await Task.Delay(1000);

                for (int row = 2; row < rowCount; row++)
                {
                    var name = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value?.ToString();
                    var dob = worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value?.ToString();
                    var nid = worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value?.ToString();
                    var url = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value?.ToString();

                    if (name == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    await page.GoToAsync(url);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await page.TypeAsync("input[name=name]", name);
                    await page.TypeAsync("input[name=dob]", dob);
                    await page.TypeAsync("input[name=id]", id);
                    var cellNumber = "H" + row;

                    worksheet.Cells[cellNumber].Value = "Verified";
                    bool dialogAccepted = false;

                    page.Dialog += async (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.Dialog != null && !dialogAccepted)
                        {
                            await e.Dialog.Accept();
                            dialogAccepted = true;
                        }


                    };




                    await page.ClickAsync("#verify_button_button");
                    await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
                    await Task.Delay(3000);


                    if (dialogAccepted)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[cellNumber].Value = "Not Verified";
                       
                    }

                    //var button = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("#update_button");
                    //var displayStyle = await button.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("element => getComputedStyle(element).display");

                    //if (displayStyle == "block") {
                    //    worksheet.Cells[cellNumber].Value = "Verified";

                    //}

                    //if (button != null)
                    //{
                    //    string initialText = await button.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("element => element.textContent");
                    //    await button.ClickAsync();
                    //    await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);

                    //    string updatedText = await button.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("element => element.textContent");

                    //    if (initialText == updatedText)
                    //    {
                    //     worksheet.Cells[cellNumber].Value = "Not Verified";

                    //    }

                    //}
                }

                await browser.CloseAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Automation failed.");
                return View("Error");
            }

           
            package.Save();
            string savePath = @"FilePath";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, package.GetAsByteArray());

            return RedirectToAction("UploadFile", "Excel");
        }
```

Now, the issue with my code is When the Data inputted is valid it is still looking for a dialog or alert which does not appear when the data is valid.
Is there any way in puppeteer sharp to check wether the AlertBox is present or not?

Comment: I think that after the `await Task.Delay(3000);` you can assume that the dialog was whether dismissed or it didn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, in terms of correct data there is no alert/Dialog showing and only in terms of incorrect data the alert is shown . The Alert/Dialog box is dependent on whether submitted data is correct/incorrect. With my previous code, I was getting `PuppeteerSharp.MessageException: Protocol error (Page.handleJavaScriptDialog): No dialog is showing` exception in terms of correct data submission and as a result my code was getting terminated without performing the complete automation. So, here how I tried to fix it. I simply used a try catch block to catch the exception and it worked.

```
 page.Dialog += async (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await e.Dialog.Dismiss();
                        }
                        catch (Exception dialogEx)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(dialogEx, "Error handling dialog.");
                        }
                    };
```